# Python BS4 Scraping Script Timer

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to get this web scraping script working properly, and am not sure what to try next. Hoping someone here knows what I should do.

I am using BS4 and the problem is whenever a URL takes a long time to load it skips over that URL (leaving an output file with fewer inputs in times of high page load times). I have been trying to add on a timer so that it only skips over the url if it doesn't load in x seconds.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using multi threading or multiprocessing to spawn threads, i think it will spawn a thread for every request and it won't skip over the url if it's taking too long.